# How to apply `lapply` function to a set of time series data set

Tags: r, lapply

I have time-series data. The data contains four univariate time-series columns over several years.  I would like to fit `ARIMA` model to each univariate time-series data for each year of the first 4 years.

I tried this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forecast)
library(tseries)
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
data("EuStockMarkets")
dat <- EuStockMarkets
res <- lapply(split(as.zoo(EuStockMarkets), as.integer(time(EuStockMarkets))), as.ts)
datNew <- lapply(5:8, function(i) ts(res[[i]]))
dat.log <- lapply(1:4, function(i) log(datNew[[i]]))
dat.diff <- lapply(1:4, function(i)diff(dat.log[[i]]))
Logreturns <- dat.diff
```

The following code does not work properly as it gave me only 4 values. However, I accept it to give me 16 values (4 years, 4 univariate time series in each year)

```
Arima.model <- lapply(1:4, function(i)auto.arima(Logreturns[[i]][,i]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is double `lapply`, one to iterate over each list and another to iterate over each column of the list.

```
result <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(Logreturns), function(i) 
                 lapply(seq_len(ncol(Logreturns[[i]])), function(j)
                        auto.arima(Logreturns[[i]][,j]))), recursive = FALSE)
```